# Difference between "m_Frame.add(chartPanel); m_Frame.validate()" and "m_Frame.add(chartPanel).validate();" using jfreechart

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, jfreechart, order-of-execution

I am migrating an Eclipse RCP applilcation from Eclipse 3.0 to 4.4 and I have a class in which I create a java.awt.Frame `m_Frame` and a ChartPanel `chartPanel` using jfreechart (jfreechart-1.0.15.jar, jcommom-1.0.18.jar).

The code originally looks like this:

```
...

m_Frame.add(chartPanel);
m_Frame.validate();
```

In Eclipse RCP 3.0 this worked without problems. Now, the application just gets stuck if I am trying to create a chart.

But if I change it to this:

```
...
m_Frame.add(chartPanel).validate();
```

it works fine. I I ditch the validation entirely or validate `m_Frame` before the ChartPanel is added or use `doLayout()` it works fine.

Can somebody explain the difference between these two approaches?

I am using Eclipse RCP 4.4 and JDK 1.8.0_60

Comment: Calling `pack()` will call `validate()`. Where is `setVisible()`? Where is `invokeLater()`?

Comment: This application doesen't use Threading, so I don't have to call `invokeLater()` I guess? `pack()` doesen't work either because it calls `validate()` which then leads to the application getting stuck. The problem is that i can't change the code without explaining the reason why `validate()` worked with Eclipse RCP 3.0 but not with 4.4. One strange thing also is that I can `validate()` the ChartPanel and the Frame seperately, but I can't `validate()` the Frame after the ChartPanel has been added. I also updated jfreechart to the newest version but it didn't help.

Comment: You _do_ need `invokeLater()` like [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); `pack()` shouldn't get stuck; please edit your question with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the method `doLayout()` instead of `validate()`, which did the job just fine.